# How to add images to listview in uwp?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, dynamically-generated

I want to create a image dynamically and add to listview.

And then, when i click the button, the other image is added, moved or updated new image to listview.

---

I used the stackpanel, but it didn't work as I thought.

Add function works well but remove or update wasn't

I think that the index value has trouble during processing

Here is my code

Please any help! Thanks.

```
async void Thumb_save(int index)
    {
        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        sampleFile_thumb_back = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(MainPage.filename_thumb + index + ".jpg",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        StorageFile file_thumb_back = sampleFile_thumb_back;

        IRandomAccessStream stream_thumb_back = await file_thumb_back.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        using (IOutputStream outputStream_thumb_back = stream_thumb_back.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
        {
            await ink1.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(outputStream_thumb_back);

            await outputStream_thumb_back.FlushAsync();
        }
        stream_thumb_back.Dispose();

        imgThumbnail_back = await file_thumb_back.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 200, ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail);

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        bitmapImage.SetSource(imgThumbnail_back);


        Image img = new Image();

        img_stack.Children.Add(img); // Here, I add the image to my stackpanel

        img.Source = bitmapImage;

        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use MVVM to bind the image to ViewModel and View.

In Model, you can write the List that includes the Image.

```
public class ImageThumbnail
{
    public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

In ViewModel, you can insert, remove, update the Image.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageThumbnail> ImageThumbnailList { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<ImageThumbnail>();

    public void ThumbRemove(int index)
    {
        ImageThumbnailList.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void ThumbUpdate(BitmapImage image, int index)
    {
        ImageThumbnailList.RemoveAt(index);
        ImageThumbnailList.Insert(index, new ImageThumbnail()
        {
            ImageSource = image
        });
    }

    public async Task Thumb_save(int index)
    {
        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        var filename_thumb = "xx"; // I dont have filename thumb that you should replace it to your code.

        var sampleFile_thumb_back = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename_thumb + index + ".jpg",
            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        // we suggeste that use camelCase. Try to replace sampleFileThumbBack to sampleFile_thumb_back

        StorageFile file_thumb_back = sampleFile_thumb_back;

        IRandomAccessStream stream_thumb_back =
            await file_thumb_back.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        using (IOutputStream outputStream_thumb_back = stream_thumb_back.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
        {
            // for I dont have any ink that you should uncomment in your code
            //await ink1.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(outputStream_thumb_back);

            //await outputStream_thumb_back.FlushAsync();
        }

        stream_thumb_back.Dispose();

        var imgThumbnail_back =
            await file_thumb_back.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 200,
                ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail);

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        bitmapImage.SetSource(imgThumbnail_back);

        ImageThumbnailList.Add(new ImageThumbnail()
        {
            ImageSource = bitmapImage
        });
    }
}
```

You should bind ViewModel to xaml.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new ViewModel();
}

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ImageThumbnailList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ImageThumbnail">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind ImageSource}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! and first I'm really Sorry for my explanation.
Because I want to my ink file to save image file and then add to listview.
Is that impossible? then, Could it be an image file already saved?

Comment: Yes for you can save the ink to file and load it to Image

Comment: I'm sorry late reply, but I don't know how to solve this. I have problems about the index value. Updating an image in imagelist throws an exception error that the index is not in range. 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'
This is my error message. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: @Kay From the error info, it should be your index is large than the collection's size. Please pay attention to the last index in your Collection in your code. If you are still stuck in this issue, please provide a simple sample and clarify your issue clearly by editing your question, then we can help you on the way.